# Simplify formula $\tau \ln(\frac {V\lim}{V_o + V\lim}) + \tau(V_o +V\lim) \cdot(1 - \frac{V\lim}{V_o + V\lim}) $

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic

I'm trying to resolve something, but I can't figure out how to simplify this formula.

from

$\tau \ln(\frac {V\lim}{V_o + V\lim}) + \tau(V_o +V\lim) \cdot(1 - \frac{V\lim}{V_o + V\lim}) $

To

$\tau (V_o - V\lim \cdot \ln(1+ \frac{V_o}{V\lim})) $

I'm stuck there:

$\tau [\ln(\frac {V\lim}{V_o + V\lim}) +(V_o +V\lim) \cdot(1 - \frac{V\lim}{V_o + V\lim})] $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(V_o +Vlim) \cdot(1 - \frac{Vlim}{V_o + Vlim})=(V_o +Vlim)\frac{V_o +Vlim-Vlim}{V_o +Vlim}=V_o$$
For the first part, you are missing a $Vlim$ term before the logarithm.
The rest is using $$\ln\frac{Vlim}{V_0+Vlim}=-\ln \frac{V_0+Vlim}{Vlim}=-\ln(1+\frac{V_o}{Vlim})$$

Comment: Thanks alot! it works

Answer (score 0):

Typing long symbols can be simplified by substitution with shorter symbols $V_0=a, V_{lim}=z$ ( first,last) values..so there is less distraction of attention from similar variable being typed.

$\tau$ common factor.

First part

$$ \log \dfrac{z}{a+z}= -\log \dfrac{a+z}{a} = -\log (1+z/a) =p $$

Second part
$$ (a+z)(1-\dfrac{z}{a+z}) = a $$

So
$$\rightarrow \;\tau(p+a)$$